How do I display the list items on the site as links
This is my question and I'm just starting to learn django ^-^
these are urls
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),

    path('<int:days_week>/', views.get_info_week_intoviy),
    path('<str:days_week>/', views.get_info_week, name = 'day-week'),
    path('type/', views.teplt, name='types'),

]

def teplt(request, types):
    dnay = ['CHETNIY', 'NECHETNIY']
    rez = ''
    for typess in dnay:
        new_ser = reverse('types', args = (typess,))
        rez += f'<li><a href="{new_ser}">{typess}</a></li>'
    response = f'''
    
    <ol>
        {rez}
    </ol>
    
    '''
    return HttpResponse(response)



this is the part of the code that should output as links along such a path http://127.0.0.1:8000/HOROS/type
CHETNIY
NECHETNIY
I tried to fix the url and view somehow, but all attempts were in vain and returned to the previous code
